# Disagreement of Ricci scalars

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

This question pertains a particular example, but I think the answer should be a general statement on a broader misundertanding I must have.

Consider a 3-sphere with metric $g=d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2+\cos^2\theta d\chi^2$. Take the diagonal vielbein $e_1{}^1=1$, $e_2{}^2=\sin\theta$ and $e_3{}^3=\cos\theta$. The resulting spin connection has non-vanishing components $$\omega_2{}^{21}=-\omega_2{}^{12}=\cos\theta,\qquad \omega_3{}^{13}=-\omega_3{}^{31}=\sin\theta.$$

I can then calculate the curvature of the spin connection, $R_{\mu\nu}{}^{ab}$, and find the contraction
$$R_{ab}{}^{ab}=e^\mu{}_ae^\nu{}_bR_{\mu\nu}{}^{ab}=2.$$

Shouldn't this be the Ricci scalar, $R=6$? Is the contraction of the curvature of the spin connection not necessarily equal to the Ricci scalar, even if the coordinates used are the same? (In fact, I just tried a different vielbein and found $R_{ab}{}^{ab}=18$ -- does the contraction $R_{ab}{}^{ab}$ depend on the chosen vielbein?)

Comment: (a) I think the metric for a 3 sphere is $g=d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\left[d\phi^2 
+ \sin^2\phi d\chi^2\right]$ ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere#Hyperspherical_coordinates)) -- you may want to double check your expression. (b) There are different conventions for the Riemann tensor that can differ by factors of the spatial dimension ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature#Traditional_notation)), so you may want to check that you are using the same convention as whatever source gave you the answer.

Comment: (c) The Ricci scalar is a scalar (its value at a point is independent of coordinates, and for a constant-curvature surface like the 3-sphere its value is just a coordinate-independent constant) and the overall method you are using to compute it is valid, so if you've accounted for (a) and (b) and are still getting the wrong answer, then it seems you made an algebra mistake. Based on your description, there's no subtle differential geometry concept you are missing.

Comment: Apologies about point (a), I was not aware of the existence of [Hopf coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere#Hopf_coordinates). Points (b) and (c) stand, however.

Comment: @Andrew For (b) you probably mean the *Ricci* tensor, not the Riemann tensor. Anyway, OP: with the conventions as laid out in Spivak/Lee (not the ones in Wikipedia) which seem to be what you’re using as well, I get the scalar curvature for a unit round sphere $S^n$ to be $n(n-1)$ (more generally, for a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ of dimension $n$ and constant sectional curvature $a$, I get a Ricci tensor of $(n-1)a\cdot g$, and scalar curvature of $n(n-1)a$). So, in 3-dimensions, I do get $R=6$ for $S^3$. At this stage I think you’ll just have to locate your algebraic mistake.